# How would a naga swim underwater?

Tags: creature-design, anatomy, mythical-creatures

Naga is a mix of a human torso and the lower body of a serpent. With this combination, how would they move when they swim?

Comment: They would move awesomely. They would swim as if they were born to it, like true creatures of the water. The grace of their movements would stun anybody who saw them for the first time. The powerful undulations of their serpentine body would propulse them through water faster than the fastest human swimmer, putting to shame even the strongest crocodile. The strokes of their long tails they would churn the water like the propeller of a speedboat. Their swift and silent swimming would make them close any distance in no time. The elegance of their swimming movements would be a sight to behold.

Comment: Uh, I get the closure for being opinion-based, but why 2 votes for being off-topic, not about worldbuilding?

Comment: Hi @Ariel, your question could use a little more details from my point-of-view. What do you mean by "how do they move?"? Are you asking on how they are physically moving the water and themselves around, or perhaps what is the optimal way for them to swim instead?

Comment: (Also, on this site you're supposed to show you have made efforts in your research, especially when regarding why you are stuck on this problem. Beyond being a reason to upvlte a question, this helps us understand what's preventing you from getting your answer alone and help you specifically on that part. Here, have you looked for videos about snakes swimming? Or perhaps its close-looking cousins, eels?)

Answer (score 6):

**Much like an Anaconda Swims**

I'm avoiding citing Sea Snakes or similar who have adaptions specifically for swimming (e.g. flattened tails) - so primary movement would be with the tail.

The hands would mostly be at the sides, however, depending on the environment - if it's an area that's got lots of things to grab and hold/move around (like a swampy grove for example) then you'd see a lot more usage of the hands.

Comment: It's not worth me adding my own answer as it would just be the same as this, but there's some visual representations of the Naga swimming in World of Warcraft, additionally they feature in [this Warcraft trailer](https://youtu.be/_bgObmIBYVc?si=2J9f7HKCxTgRcKDV&t=89)

Answer (score 4):

Sea snakes move their tails side to side (lateral undulation) like sharks and unlike dolphins. Your naga can do the same. The human portion just uses it's arms for steering and the propulsion comes mostly from the tail. Sea snakes have flattened ends to their tails which assists with this.